# RCurl multiple API calls generate infinite connections

Tags: r, api, curl, rcurl

I am using RCurl to handle multiple http request at once. (I have no problem using `httr::GET` and `RJSONIO`, but have several million records.)

I am using fcc.gov api to convert lat, long information to census block level (FIPS code).

Basically, I have list of URL's that will return in JSON format.

```
> head(urls)
[1] "http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?format=json&latitude=42.644825&longitude=-83.40611&showall=false"   
[2] "http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?format=json&latitude=40.8434&longitude=-74.540344&showall=false" 
> res[1:1000] = str_extract(as.character(getURL(urls[1:1000])),
 "[0-9]{15}")
```

This is basically how I am handling `getURL` function, and extracting the relevant information without converting JSON to df in R, which is unnecessary.

One `getURL` call request 1000 requests at a time, and I am looping over several million records.

The problem is that it makes one connection for each instance and never disconnects or closes in libcurl level.
When I try to write the final output to csv or RDS file, it cannot handle and gives system error "Too many open files".

```
> write.csv(res, "res1.csv", row.names = F)  
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :  
  cannot open the connection  
Calls: write.csv -> eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> write.table -> file  
In addition: Warning message:  
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :  
  cannot open file 'res1.csv': Too many open files  
Execution halted  
sh: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file:   Error 24
```

I can use base `url` and `close`, but for massive data, I would need to use RCurl for efficiency. However, with such limitation, I am not able to proceed.

There seems to be no alternative in R that can handle multiple http requests at a time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `getURIAsynchronous` ?  What's wrong with `httr::GET`?

Comment: It's not usually a great idea to hammer someones server with thousands of simultaneous request.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain httr:GET can only request 1 URL at a time. getURIAsynchronous is function that is being called by getURL. It seems like R cannot pass optional arguments to libcurl.

Comment: @hadley What do you think is a reasonable number of request at a time? I do not want to hammer other's server, but on the other hand, one request at a time will take forever, even with multithread processing.

Comment: @won782 I normally try not to do more than 1 per second. If you are trying to get all the data, I'd recommend contacting the API maintainers first.